# Do I have to cure a fresh ham before smoking?

Tags: smoking, ham, curing

I have a fresh ham. Do I need to cure it somehow before I put it in the stove-top smoker?

Answer (score 4):

Trying to smoke a fresh ham will result in something that tastes like cooked pork.  You may impart some smokey crust on the outside, but it will still taste like cooked pork.

Curing and then smoking is the only way to give a true smoked ham flavor, and please learn about curing a fresh ham, a cure applied to the outside of a fresh ham will not penetrate to the bone of a ham.

Roger

Comment: Thank you now I will just have to figure out how to cure it